# Android Google Play Services-Vision Source code

Tags: android, google-vision

Where can I find the source code for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0`?

I can't find it anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: You would luckier on Google than here for this kind of question...

Comment: I'd like to extend `TextRecognizer`, but it's marked `final`, so I don't think Google is letting us go there.  Have you made any progress?